# Filter out calm parts of audio, let through really loud ones

Tags: premiere, audio

I have a project where I have one video and two audio tracks. The first audio is from the line-in microphone, the second one is from the room environment.

I only want the second audio to play when the db level is above -5db (meaning, only when the track gets loud). The point is for the second audio to just provide the laughter (loud part) and ignore its calm parts, which just adds unnecessarily noise.

Is there an effect or a filter for this? (it's like a cutoff limiter at X db, but the opposite, cutting off anything below a determined level of volume)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! From the [Adobe Premiere effects help][1]:

> Dynamics effect The Dynamics effect provides a set of controls that
>   can be combined or used independently to adjust audio. Use either the
>   graphical controls in the Custom Setup view, or adjust values in the
>   Individual Parameters view. This effect is available for 5.1, stereo,
>   or mono clips.
>
> **AutoGate**
>
> Cuts off a signal when the level falls below the specified threshold.
>   Use this control to remove unwanted background signals in recordings,
>   such as a background signal in a voice-over. Set the gate to close
>   whenever the speaker stops, thus removing all other sounds. The LED
>   display colors indicate the gate’s mode: open (green), attack or
>   release (yellow), and closed (red). Use the following controls for
>   Gate: Threshold
>
> Specifies the level (between –60 and 0 dB) that the incoming signal
>   must exceed to open the gate. If the signal level falls below this
>   level, the gate closes, muting the incoming signal. Attack
>
> Specifies the time the gate takes to open after the signal level
>   exceeds the threshold. Release
>
> Sets the time (between 50 and 500 milliseconds) the gate takes to
>   close after the signal level has fallen below the threshold. Hold
>
> Specifies the time (between 0.1 and 1000 milliseconds) the gate stays
>   open after the level has fallen below the threshold.
>
> [1]:
>   https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/audio-effects-transitions.html